# Starting compiz from the command line

Tags: compiz, customization

I am making a custom session (using .xsession) and I want to use compiz.  When I use the `compiz` or `compiz --replace` command in the .xsession and also using "recovery console" option, it seems to not load any plugins.  After starting compiz, I start ccsm and no plugins are loaded.

Back when I used arch there were a bunch of arguments for compiz and I would use 3 or so, and one of them told compiz to load settings from my config at launch.  Here is the `compiz --help` from Ubuntu 12.04:

```
Usage: compiz [OPTIONS] [PLUGINS ...]
Options:
  --replace             Replace any existing window managers
  --display DISPLAY     Connect to X display DISPLAY (instead of $DISPLAY)
  --sm-disable          Disable session management
  --sm-client-id ID     Session management client ID
  --keep-desktop-hints  Retain existing desktop hints
  --sync                Make all X calls synchronous
  --debug               Enable debug mode
  --version             Show the program version
  --help                Show this summary
```

Those are also the only options under `man compiz`

Here's the thing: when I run `compiz --replace` under the unity session, plugins load alright and all that good stuff.  When I run that under my session, compiz loads nothing.

Info that may help:

- I have tried compiz --replace gconf
- I always have gnome-settings-daemon running
- I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (beta release)

Comment: Have you gone to CCSM and enabled the plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Go to "startup applications" and create a application launcher.

```
Name = Compiz
Command = compiz --replace
Comment = start compiz
```

[image]

Comment: How does this help me?

Comment: once the OS loads the startup application kicks in and loads compiz. The same as going to a terminal and typing `compiz --replace` give it a try....I use it for that exact reason

Comment: No, whenever i do that it doesn't load any plugins.  I AM NOT REPLACING A RUNNING INSTANCE OF COMPIZ OR ANY OTHER WINDOW MANAGER!  I need compiz to LOAD PLUGINS!

Comment: you know that "mutter" is the default composer so running compiz in 12.04 might not work

Comment: Unity uses compiz....

Comment: @blueXrider wrong - compiz is the default in Ubuntu 12.04 if you have gone with the normal flavour (ie, not Xubuntu/Kubuntu).

Comment: I have to say this is simple solution to make compiz run on startup and still works on Ubuntu Mate 17.04

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify compiz config to use gconf as configuration backend when upgrading 11.10 -> 12.04.

```
/etc/compizconfig/config:

[general]
#backend = ini
backend = gconf
integration = true
plugin_list_autosort = true
```

After this modification, running `compiz --replace` in `.xsession` resulted behavior I was used to in 11.10.